# How to define a function that would move files to given directories?

Tags: python

I need to define a function that will copy files from one directory to TRAINING and TESTING directories given the split size (so for example if split size = 0.9, 90% of the files go to TRAINING). The condition is that the file can't be of size 0 and the files should be randomized. this is what I've managed to think of, but it doesn't work.

```py
def split_data(SOURCE, TRAINING, TESTING, SPLIT_SIZE):
    file = os.listdir(SOURCE)
    file = os.path.getsize(SOURCE) > 0
    if file:
            copyfile(random.sample(SOURCE, SPLIT_SIZE), TRAINING),
            copyfile(random.sample(SOURCE, 1-SPLIT_SIZE), TESTING)
```

When I try to run this function an error comes up:

```
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

Can you please tell me how to define a function that will take the following arguments (this is what it must look like since it's part of an assignment in a course)?:

```
def split_data(SOURCE, TRAINING, TESTING, SPLIT_SIZE)
```

Thank you, Joanna

PS: I'm reposting my previous question changing its content as suggested by one of the users, so that it's more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one such method:

```
def split_data(SOURCE, TRAINING, TESTING, SPLIT_SIZE):
   source_files = [f for f in os.listdir(SOURCE) if os.path.getsize(f) > 0]
   random.shuffle(source_files)
   total = len(source_files)
   to_training = source_files[0: int(total * SPLIT_SIZE)]
   to_test = source_files[int(total * SPLIT_SIZE):]
   for f in to_training:
      copyfile(os.path.join(SOURCE, f), TRAINING)
   for f in to_test:
      copyfile(os.path.join(SOURCE, f), TESTING)
   assert len(source_files) == len(to_training) + len(to_test)
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you so much! I've run it an got such error: 
`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'cat.2275.jpg'`
It's probably something I did previously, Any idea where to search for a mistake?

Comment: Are you sure to use the `os.path.join(SOURCE, f)` method of naming files? That should handle expanding out your `cat.2275.jpg` to `/path/to/SOURCE/cat.2275.jpg`.

Comment: That's how I used this function later: `CAT_SOURCE_DIR = "/tmp/PetImages/Cat/"
TRAINING_CATS_DIR = "/tmp/cats-v-dogs/training/cats/"
TESTING_CATS_DIR = "/tmp/cats-v-dogs/testing/cats/"
DOG_SOURCE_DIR = "/tmp/PetImages/Dog/"
TRAINING_DOGS_DIR = "/tmp/cats-v-dogs/training/dogs/"
TESTING_DOGS_DIR = "/tmp/cats-v-dogs/testing/dogs/"

split_size = .9
split_data(CAT_SOURCE_DIR, TRAINING_CATS_DIR, TESTING_CATS_DIR, split_size)
split_data(DOG_SOURCE_DIR, TRAINING_DOGS_DIR, TESTING_DOGS_DIR, split_size)`

Comment: Assuming then that it crashed in the call for cats, does the file `/tmp/PetImages/Cat/cat.2275.png` exist? It would also help to have `copyfile`'s source, if you have it.

Comment: When called this line, the output was 1500: `print(len(os.listdir('/tmp/PetImages/Cat/')))`
This is the source put in the function: `"/tmp/PetImages/Cat/"`